# Defining a class member that has required constructor arguments in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Suppose I have a class `Foo` whose constructor has a required argument. And further suppose that I'd like to define another class `Bar` which has as a member an object of type `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
private:
   int x;
public:
    Foo(int x) : x(x) {};
};

class Bar {
private:
    Foo f(5);
};
```

Compiling this will give errors (in this exact case, g++ gives "`error: expected identifier before numeric constant`"). For one, `Foo f(5);` looks like a function definition to the compiler, but I actually want `f` to be an instance of `Foo` initialized with the value 5. I could solve the issue using pointers:

```
class Foo {
private:
   int x;
public:
    Foo(int x) : x(x) {};
};

class Bar {
private:
    Foo* f;
public:
    Bar() { f = new Foo(5); }
};
```

But is there a way around using pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have C++11 support, can initialize `f` at the point of declaration, but not with round parentheses `()`:

```
class Bar {
private:
    Foo f{5}; // note the curly braces
};
```

Otherwise, you need to use `Bar`'s constructor initialization list.

```
class Bar {
public:
    Bar() : f(5) {}
private:
    Foo f;
};
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I see how this works now, and it helps me better understand when values are initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Your version with pointers is very close - modify it as follows (see comments below):

```
class Foo {
private:
   int x;
public:
    Foo(int x) : x(x) {};
};

class Bar {
private:
    Foo f;          // Make f a value, not a pointer
public:
    Bar() : f(5) {} // Initialize f in the initializer list
};
```